# Do While, Loop not finding files after initial loop

Tags: excel, vba

The loop was working until I added the If/ElseIf statement to differentiate between two different files that start with either and "N" or "V".everything seems to be ok, but after it loops initially it skips right by the If statement into the elseif.  I was watching in the local window and it's assigning the next file correctly, but the script treats it as if it doesn't have a "V" at the beginning, when it really does.  Suggestions?  Thanks!

Here's the piece having trouble:

```
folderPath = myDir
If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath + "\"
filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xls")
Do While filename <> ""
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wbkCS = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
    If filename = Dir(folderPath & "V*" & "*.xls") Then
        wbkCS.Worksheets("Cut Sheet").Range("S4:S2000").Copy
        With wbkVer.Worksheets("Cutsheets")
            .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With
    ElseIf filename = Dir(folderPath & "N*" & "*.xls") Then
        wbkCS.Worksheets("PON Cut Sheet").Range("AV3:AV2000").Copy
        With wbkVer.Worksheets("Cutsheets")
            .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With
    End If

    filename = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Remy Porter noted, your repeated use of the Dir function grabs messed up entries each time you use it.

`If filename = Dir(folderPath & "V*" & "*.xls") Then`
This line will, each time again, grab the first match for `V**.xls` from that path. This is certainly not what you want.

In Excel VBA you can use `like` as the simplest solution:
`If filename like "N*.xls" Then`

(And you should not use those double `**`)

Comment: Thank you, this was the quick and dirty way. As for the double "**" I had been just spitballing trying out different things, but normally I wouldn't do that. :)  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this:-

```
If filename = Dir(folderPath & "V*" & "*.xls") Then
```

- Do the following using a `Regex`

Code:

```
Function ContainsAMatch(ByRef fileName as String) as Boolean
Dim regex as Object
Dim strtxt As String

  strtxt = fileName
  Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

  With regex
    '-- matches first letter to be V and last set to be .xls
    .Pattern = "^(V)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(.xls)$"   
    .Global = True
    If regex.Test(strTxt) Then
      containsAMatch = True
    Else
      containsAMatch = False
    End If
  End With

End Sub
```

- Another way to find if there's `V` and `.xls` using `instr`

e.g. Filename = "Vvtmvy89file.xls"

Code:

```
If InStr(Left(filename,1),"V") > 0 then 
  If InStr(filename, ".xls") > 0 then
    '-- Do Something
  End If
End IF
```

PS: Updated the code to have the exact `Regex`.

Comment: The check should be for N and V at the start of the file name only, isn't it?

Comment: Yup you are right KekuSemau. BTW @Mike, `Regex` could be an over-kill compared to `like` ;) not saying coz it's my answer. Saying for the sake of better performance for you. Give it a try when you think you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Dir is a sort of messed up function. Calling Dir with no parameters looks back at the *last* call to Dir, and gets the next file that meets that criteria. So your last line, `filename = Dir` is now getting the next file that either meets the Dir criteria in your if or elseif.

You should use [the filesystem objects](http://www.vb123.com/index.html?200408_cw_fso.htm) instead.